# Usage of 'that much more' in a scientific article

Tags: grammar, colloquialisms, science

Would it be acceptable to use the phrase "*that much more*" in the context of a scientific article?

Basically, I want to convey this:

"*The results were obtained doing A. We expect that doing B, taking into account C and D, is that much more cumbersome.*".

I'm not sure if the phrase is used rather colloquially, or whether it can be used in a formal context.

Comment: You're right in that "*that much more*" can be improved. Please add more information about what A and B are and about what kind of encumbrance is involved. Words like *effectively* and *significantly* have technical meanings that might be just right in this case. Given more context, another word might strongly suggest itself.

Comment: I've expanded a bit on the intended use. I'm sorry can't go into finer details, but this is part of a yet unpublished article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that *that much* abstractly refers to a quantity which isn't given any reference or anchor. While not grammatically incorrect, it doesn't actually convey specific information about *how* much, any more than *lots*.

You can gain that emphasis by first asserting that things will be cumbersome, and then asserting that C & D will magnifying that further.

> "The results were obtained doing A.  We expect that doing B would be considerably more cumbersome, especially when C and D are taken into account."

That's a slightly different meaning, since it implies B alone is much more cumbersome.  If that isn't true, you can adjust to:

> "The results were obtained doing A.  We expect that doing B would be considerably more cumbersome, when C and D are taken into account."

Answer (score 1):

> "The results were obtained doing A. We expect that doing B, taking into account C and D, *would be* **unproductively** more cumbersome."

This could be rearranged, as suggested by a comment below:

> "The results were obtained doing A. We expect that doing B, taking into account C and D, would be more cumbersome and no more productive."

Comment: I'd say "...more cumbersome, but not better."

Comment: Noted well and revised